# MKMapView "lock" userTrackingMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

When setting the `userTrackingMode` of an `MKMapView` I want to be able to "lock" the tracking mode even when a user moves the map.

Currently if I set it to `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` and then move the map (or zoom in) it will revert back to `MKUserTrackingModeNone` automatically.

Is this possible?

Comment: Usually for map, you will have a `back to current location button`, so you can set back `userTrackingMode` in that action

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate, you can respond to `mapView(_:didChange:animated:)` by setting the map's `userTrackingMode`.

But is that really a good idea? That will snap the user pin back to the center of the map, so to the user it will seem that he moved the map and it moved right back. It would be better, surely, to prevent the user from moving the map in the first place (easily done).

The canonical thing to do is just to give the user an MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem so that the choice of mode is always up to the user.

Comment: I do have a `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` for my users. But, consider this scenario. Using `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` the user is navigating and the map is following them with heading. Then pinch the map to zoom in, but `MKMapView` sees this as "moving" the map and reverts back to the default trackingMode. This is super annoying to user who then have to switch back to `heading` mode over and over when zooming in or just moving the map a bit.

Comment: "This is super annoying to user" The Maps app behaves that way and I, the user, am not super annoyed.

Comment: But you are not a user of our app. :)

Comment: No, but I would opine that most users are used to what the Maps app does. Anyway, the first paragraph of my answer does answer your question; you can't stop the tracking mode from changing, but you can certainly respond to its changing by changing it back.